# Highscore changing to array list and sort it by time

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, file-io

I need help with sort the inputfile/highscore i've tried Holder-comparator, Collections.Sort and im now trying to make it an array list so the highscore is sorted by time i have tried but failed, I am really stuck have been stuck for days. Anny sugestions would be lovely

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class game {

private static void  start() throws IOException {
    int number = (int) (Math.random() * 1001);
    BufferedReader reader;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String scorefile = "p-lista_java";
    int försök = 0;
    int gissning = 0;
    String namn;
    String line = null;
    String y;
    String n;
    String val ;
    String quit = "quit";
    String Gissning;

    System.out.println("Hello and welcome to this guessing game" +
            "\nStart guessing it's a number between 1 and 1000: ");

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (true || (!( input.next().equals(quit)))){   


        System.out.print("\nEnter your guess: ");
        gissning = input.nextInt();
        försök++;

        if (gissning == number ){
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long gameTime = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("Yes, the number is " + number + 
                    "\nYou got it after " + försök + " guesses " + " times in " + (int)(gameTime/1000) + " seconds.");
            System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
            namn = reader.readLine();


            try {
                BufferedWriter outfile
                        = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(scorefile, true));
                outfile.write(namn + " " + försök +"\t" + (int)(gameTime/1000) + "\n");
                outfile.close();
            } catch (IOException exception) {

            }
         break;

        }

         if( gissning < 1 || gissning > 1000 ){
                System.out.println("Stupid guess! I wont count that..." );
                --försök;
         }

         else if (gissning > number){
            System.out.println(" Your guess is too high");
         }
        else 
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
    }

        try {
            BufferedReader infile
                        = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(scorefile));
            while ((line = infile.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            infile.close();

        } catch (IOException exception) {

    }

    System.out.println("Do you want to continue (Y/N)?");
       val=reader.readLine();

       if ((val.equals("y"))||(val.equals("Y"))){
           game.start();
       }
       else 
           System.out.print("Thanks for playing");
       System.exit(0);

}


    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

       game.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly are trying to sort from this code? Do you want to put the scores sorted in the file or sort them after you read them back? Please be more specific.

Comment: Instead of sorting by time, it is often simpler to preserve insertion order. E.g. A List or LinkedHashMap/Set does this by default.

Comment: I want the the output to be sorted by time

Comment: You can read your file into an array or list, sort it and display results to the user. Or you can read your file, add a new record, sort it and rewrite the file. I don't think there is a simple way to append your line in the middle of the file. Btw, you can use a database to store your scores. Might be an overkill for such a simple task, but solves the sorting problem =)

Comment: You can also give us an example of Input and Output data that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Probably the simplest one is to sort the scores before printing them to the screen. First, put the score lines in a list.

```
BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(scorefile));
List<String> scores = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = infile.readLine()) != null) {
    scores.add(line);
}
infile.close();
```

Now you can sort the list. You can use the `sort` method of the `Collections` class, but you will have to use a custom `Comparator` for this. Since your highscores are formatted like `<name>\t<steps>\t<time>` you can `split` the lines at whitespaces, parse the third element as a number and compare those numbers.

```
Collections.sort(scores, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int t1 = Integer.parseInt(s1.split("\\s")[2]); // time in s1
        int t2 = Integer.parseInt(s2.split("\\s")[2]); // time in s2
        return t1 - t2;                                // neg. if t1 < t2
    } 
});
```

This will sort the list of `scores` in-place, so now all that's left to do is to actually print the scores:

```
System.out.println("Name       Steps  Time");
for (String s : scores) {
    String[] ps = s.split("\\s");
    System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %5s %5s", ps[0], ps[1], ps[2]));
}
```

Comment: Why not using a `TreeSet` along with the same comparator? It would save you the sort since it would happen at insert time...

Comment: @aymeric I wanted to keep it simple and separate the read/sort/write steps, but using a `TreeSet` is indeed a neat idea.

Comment: @tobias_k no it didnt work i tried but it didnt work, it might be that im writing something wrong

Comment: @tobias_k when i put the codings in the highscore wont print and when i change the coding to match the the ints and strings i get errors in the output. 
Im sorry i dont really know how to explain much i am new at java but how have you put the codings in did u make a new static string?

Comment: Just tried it again. Replace the part of your code where you read and print the highscores file (lines 68-73) with the three pieces of code from my answer. If it still does not work, update your question with the error you get.